# jQuery mouseenter causing a flicker

Tags: jquery

I have a site that where when you roll over an image, a  block of text displays over the image.

The desired affect is achieved, except for the fact that if your cursor is over the new text element over the image everything starts flickering.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/aRSw2/

```
Here's the JS:

$('.campaign-1').on('mouseenter', function(){
  $(this).addClass('campaign-hover');
  $('.cta').show();
});
$('.campaign-1').on('mouseleave', function(){
  $('.campaign-hover').removeClass('campaign-hover');
  $('.cta').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your `span` into your section, else your `mouseenter` and `leave` are constantly being triggered causing a flicker:

```
<section class="campaign-1">
<a href="#"><img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png"/></a>
<span class="cta"> Hello </span>
</section>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aRSw2/2/

Answer (score 1):

Although what @tymeJV said is true but in certain scenarios you may not be able to do the same.

So try the Following

```
$('.campaign-1,a').on('mouseenter', function(){
        $(this).addClass('campaign-hover'); 
        $('.cta').show();   
});
```

Updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aRSw2/4/)

Comment: Thanks Akshay, I would actually prefer to not move the span in my dom, although that was not explained in my question. I like your solution, but in the fiddle the </a> was not closed out. When I close the </a> the flicker comes back. Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you cursor over the new text element then it is receiving focus, and the `campaign` section loses focus (resulting in your text losing focus, the campgain re-gaining it, and the text re-appearing).

Modify your code so that the text popup remains visible while either the campaign element, or the text element have the mouse over them.

Here's an update to your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W3wEd/

```
$('.campaign-1').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).addClass('campaign-hover');
    updateHover();
});
$('.campaign-1').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $('.campaign-hover').removeClass('campaign-hover');
    updateHover();
});
$('.cta').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).addClass('cta-hover');
    updateHover();
});
$('.cta').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('cta-hover');
    updateHover();
});

function updateHover() {
    if ($('.campaign-1').hasClass('campaign-hover') || $('.cta').hasClass('cta-hover'))
    {
        $('.cta').show();        
    } else {
        $('.cta').hide();
    } 
};
```